# How to add custom field in the JSESSIONID cookie in Jetty

Tags: http, session, cookies, jetty, jsessionid

I'm trying to add some custom attribute in the `JSESSIONID` cookie sent by the Jetty container. I want to add the hostname of the server that handled the request. Currently, the `domain` attribute of the cookie I receive contains the FQDN of the load-balancer. I want to either replace it or add another custom attribute (say "source_server") with value equal to the responding server hostname. Is this possible?

The alternative, I suppose, is to create a new cookie using `HttpServletResponse.addCookie()` method with the data I want.

Comment: The cookie sent back can only contain the domain for the Host that processed the request.   Have you setup your `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` properly for your LoadBalancer?  And have you configured your LoadBalancer to report the [RFC7239](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239) `Forwarded` header properly to Jetty?